# Should we follow the actions of our prophet ditto like him?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, prophet-muhammad

Why do we follow Hadith? Did our prophet told us to follow same actions like him? Why do all the Muslims follow the actions same ditto like him? Did he tell us to do that?

Comment: Allah told us to follow the Prophet () in several verses in the quran.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a right way to do things and then there are wrong ways to do  things. *Very, very wrong ways*. We should follow the actions of our Prophet, if went want to go to Jannah (Paradise).

Allah (ﷻ) said, ومن يشاقق الرسول من بعد ما تبين له الهدى ويتبع غير سبيل المؤمنين نوله ما تولى ونصله جهنم وساءت مصيرا ("..whoever opposes the Messenger after guidance has become clear to him and **follows other than the way of the believers** – We will give him what he has taken and **drive him into Hell**, and evil it is as a destination”) – Qur’an 4:115.

This "way of the believers" is what the Prophet (ﷺ) taught and showed us, which was then followed by his Companions & the Salaf. To follow other than what he taught us is to follow whims, innovations and maybe even Kufr/Shirk depending on the belief/action.. all of which lead to Hell.

- Allah (ﷻ) told us to follow the Prophet's (ﷺ) example/conduct, if we desire Paradise.
- The Prophet (ﷺ) told us to do as he does; to pray as he prays; etc.

There is a hadith on some men who were going to go contrary to the Prophet's actions:

> A group of three men came to the houses of the wives of the Prophet (ﷺ) asking how the Prophet (ﷺ) worshipped (Allah), and when they were informed about that, they considered their worship insufficient and said, "Where are we from the Prophet (ﷺ) as his past and future sins have been forgiven." Then one of them said, "I will offer the prayer throughout the night forever." The other said, "I will fast throughout the year and will not break my fast." The third said, "I will keep away from the women and will not marry forever." Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) came to them and said, "Are you the same people who said so-and-so? By Allah, I am more submissive to Allah and more afraid of Him than you; yet I fast and break my fast, I do sleep and I also marry women. So **he who does not follow my tradition in religion, is not from me** (not one of my followers). - Bukhari (5063).

Notice how their original thinking was that they thought they were going to do something good for the sake of righteousness. But as you can see, those actions would not have been righteous. They would've been extremism (and would've caused them troubles and health issues). The Sunnah teaches the proper way, which is also the moderate as well as good/healthy way.. and following it is the only way to Paradise; the only conduct that is accepted.